# Not possible to update to Buildship v. 2.1.2.v20170807-1324 from v. 2.0.2.v20170420-0909 in Eclipse Oxygen 4.7.0 build 20170620-1800

Tags: eclipse, gradle, gradle-eclipse, buildship, eclipse-oxygen

I've a new installation of Eclipse Oxygen v. 4.7.0 build 20170620-1800 with the Spring Tool plugin v. 3.9.0.201707061730-RELEASE.

I'm trying to update the Buildship from v. 2.0.2.v20170420-0909 to v. 2.1.2.v20170807-1324 (as noticed from the Eclipse update popup), but I've the error below:

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=C__Users_Andrea_eclipse_jee-oxygen_eclipse, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.gradleware.tooling.client,0.19.3.v20170801075239
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.gradleware.tooling.model,0.19.3.v20170801075239
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.gradleware.tooling.utils,0.19.3.v20170801075239
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.buildship.branding,2.1.2.v20170807-1324
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.buildship.core,2.1.2.v20170807-1324
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.buildship.stsmigration,2.1.2.v20170807-1324
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.buildship.ui,2.1.2.v20170807-1324
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.gradle.toolingapi,3.5.0.v20170801075239
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.buildship,2.1.2.v20170807-1324
```

Thanks a lot,
Regards,
Andrea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it isn't buildship, but an Eclipse bug.

FWIW, I followed the instructions to:

1. Go into Preferences > Install/Update -> Available Software sites
2. Uncheck Buildship
3. Open Marketplace and find Buildship 2.0
4. Click on greyed-out Install button
5. Click on enabled Update button

Not sure what the last two steps were all about, but after the update and a restart Buildship is re-enabled in Prefs and it appears to be updated successfully.

Comment: Good! Thanks a lot.